# KILabel and emojis in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, frameworks, label

I'm using the framework KILabel but I have an issue for the hashtag function.
https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel

Indeed, when a user type a hashtag with emoji(s) in it, the hastag is sent to Firebase with emoji(s). The problem is that, when the user click on the hashtag, the hashtag has no emoji(s) any more.

So, if I understand well, the function which capture the hashtag is ok with emoji(s) but the function which handle the hashtag (when we click on it) is not...

I'm beginner and I don't really understand the Objective-c

I think the problem is in this file: https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel/blob/master/KILabel/Source/KILabel.m